How do we we scan 'nunc tantum sinus et statio mala fidèle carinis'
It seems to have a syllable too many for a dactylic hexameter, but I sée no place for an élision.

My Mynors OCT has fida here instead of fidele, with no textual variation noted in the apparatus. Lewis and Short also have this line cited under fidus. Where are you seeing fidele?
With fida, the line scans normally:

NUNC TAN|TUM sinus| ET stati|O mala|FIda ca|RINIS

